# Asp.net middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, f#, asp.net-core

This code is asp.net core middleware written in f# and called from c# for a blazor server-side app. How can this be made more efficient if any in regards to the async code.

F#:

```
type CheckMaintenanceStatusMiddleWare(next : RequestDelegate) =

    let _next = next

    member this.InvokeAsync(context : HttpContext) =

        let statusCheck = true
        if statusCheck
        then 
            Task.Run(fun arg -> context.Response.Redirect("/Maintenance"))
        else 
           _next.Invoke(context)

[<Extension>]
type CheckMaintenanceStatusMiddleWareExtensions() =

    [<Extension>]
    static member inline UseCheckMaintenanceStatus(builder : IApplicationBuilder) =

        builder.UseMiddleware<CheckMaintenanceStatusMiddleWare>()
```

C#

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCheckMaintenanceStatus();

            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }



            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
```

Razor Component:

```
@page "/Maintenance"

<h3>Maintenance</h3>

@code {

}
```

Comment: @CaringDev please explain, thanks.

Comment: Hi, you should explain what your code does in your post, otherwise it's hard to tell if it can be improved.

Comment: @IEatBagels, do you have experience with Asp.net core 3? Specifically middleware, and async code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Task.Run`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8) schedules the work specified by the lambda to be executed on the thread pool.
Scheduling the work and managing the thread pool is costly in terms of CPU time, allocations and possible thread starvation. `Task.Run` is useful for CPU-bound tasks but usually a smell in asynchronous code in web applications. Most of the time it hints at misunderstanding of async vs. parallel.
As `context.Response.Redirect("/Maintenance")` is not async by itself, there is no need to block/wait/schedule work. Instead, you can synchronously instruct the response to redirect and return a premade, completed task:

```
context.Response.Redirect("/Maintenance")
Task.CompletedTask
```

or return a result directly

```
Task.FromResult(response)
```